# array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\nav-menu.php on line 93

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Im having problem with my wordpress. i have downloaded wordpress 4.3 and run it on xampp.
im trying to make my own theme in wordpress so i made a folder in wordpress\wp-content\themes.

i made my style.css, header, footer, index.php but whenever i run it, im having this error on top.
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\nav-menu.php on line 93

here is my header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title> 
            <?php
                wp_title('|', 'true', 'right'); // title of the page
                bloginfo('name');  // name of the blog

            ?>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/bootstrap.css">

        <?php wp_head(); //this is use for plugins ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="five columns clearfix">
                <a href="<?php echo get_option ('home');?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/globelogo.jpeg" title="bloginfo('title');"></a>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why would you be terminating HTML output in *header.php*?

Comment: Please share your functions.php file.